# Apple‘s LIve Photo:how the video is pre-recorded when taking pictures?

Tags: ios

I would like to build an App about capture a Live Photo but I have no idea How to record the video 1.5 seconds before the button is pressed。

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It will be nice from your side to add some code that you have tried so that the people will be able to help you more rather than asking a help on a broad topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the basic idea is to keep recording to a buffer. The buffer should hold the last `n` seconds of video (3 seconds in your case). When the button is pressed copy the buffer.

I haven't done any development in ios, so i will be of no use in providing the code.